# Customized NSTableCellView's IBOutlet is null

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstablecellview

I have a `NSTableView`, its data source and delegate have been set. And I want to customize the cell, so I dragged a view-based cell view from the library. Then I created a class `ServiceCell` which inherits from `NSTableCellView` in order to fully control my special cell. After that, I control-drag from the nib file to the cell class to create the `IBOutlet` properties of the image and text field in the cell.

In the NSTableView's delegate methods, I wrote this:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    // Get a new ViewCell
    ServiceCell *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"ServiceCell" owner:self];

    NSLog(@"Field = %@", cellView.textField); //which turns out to be null!!!

    if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"ServiceColumn"] )
    {
        cellView.serviceImage.image = nil;
        cellView.nameLabel.stringValue = @"Hello";
        return cellView;
    }
    return cellView;
}
```

As you can see, the text field is null! But `makeViewWithIdentifier:` has found the cell in Interface Builder and displayed the cell in the app window. I just cannot set it's value, Why?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I just realised I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102024/why-does-nstablecellview-alloc-init-produce-a-nil-text-field

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are accessing your textfield but not accessing its textvalue. Try your log statement like this below:-

```
NSLog(@"Field = %@", cellView.textField.stringValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

in Table view select cell and give identifier name (same as you are using in code, for your snipped it will be `@"ServiceCell"`), your code part is right it will work.