# Why does [[NSTableCellView alloc] init] produce a nil- text field?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, nstablecellview

The log lines below will show "Table cell: [valid value logged here]" but "Text field: (null)".

I'm actually trying to build an NSOutlineView programmatically, and it works with a cell-based approach, but not with a view-based approach. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
-(NSView*)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    NSTableCellView* view = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    if (view == nil) {
        view = [[NSTableCellView alloc] init];
        view.identifier = tableColumn.identifier;
    }

    view.textField.stringValue = @"TEST";

    NSLog(@"Table cell: %@", view);
    NSLog(@"Text field: %@", view.textField);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: You didn't create a textField instance there!!!

Comment: I was under the impression that the text field already existed? And also, when I tried `view.textField = [[NSTextField alloc] init]`, the application raised a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: I believe you should create a seperate textField object and `addSubview:` it to the outline's view .

Comment: ... or override `NSTableCellView` and let the subclass do it.  Which is a superior approach.

Comment: Subclassing is always a better option in these requirements.

Comment: Why is that better? Shouldn't NSTableCellView work "out of the box"? Creating a source list programmatically is rediculously difficult.

Comment: If you're going to use ``[[NSTextField alloc] init]`` to set the ``textField`` property, you need to create it, then add it as a subview of your ``NSTableCellView`` (``[view addSubview:tf]``). The ``EXC_BAD_ACCESS`` error might be caused by omitting this step. You'll also need to set the frame of your field in this method - or better, constrain it.